# Specific Practice-It ArrayList Error

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, logic, indexoutofboundsexception

I was doing some work using Practice-It(If you haven't used it before, it's a wonderful service for practicing Java, but it can be frustrating without someone to help explain your mistakes.)
I was doing the following question:

> Write a method removeShorterStrings that takes an ArrayList of Strings as a parameter and that removes from each successive pair of values the shorter string in the pair. For example, suppose that an ArrayList called list contains the following values: {"four", "score", "and", "seven", "years", "ago"} In the first pair, "four" and "score", the shorter string is "four". In the second pair, "and" and "seven", the shorter string is "and". In the third pair, "years" and "ago", the shorter string is "ago". Therefore, the call: removeShorterStrings(list); should remove these shorter strings, leaving the list as follows: "score", "seven", "years". If there is a tie (both strings have the same length), your method should remove the first string in the pair. If there is an odd number of strings in the list, the final value should be kept in the list.

Being rather new at Arraylists, I wrote the following method to solve the problem:

```
public static void removeShorterStrings(ArrayList<String> Shorty){
for(int i = Shorty.size()-1; i > 0; i-- ){
    if((Shorty.size()) % 2 == 1){

        i = i-1;
        if((Shorty.get(i)).length()<= (Shorty.get(i-1)).length()){
            Shorty.remove(i);

               if(i != 0){
            i = i-1;
        } 
        }
    }
   else if((Shorty.size()) % 2 == 0){
        if((Shorty.get(i)).length()<= (Shorty.get(i-1)).length()){
            Shorty.remove(i);
            }



         }
       if(i != 0 || i != 1){
            i = i-1; 
       }

    }

}
```

The problem then inputs the Following Strings to test the solution:

```
["four", "score", "and", "seven", "years", "ago"]
["Lots", "of  ", "ties", "in  ", "this", "test"]
["Don't", "remove", "the", "last", "string (me)"]
["Don't remove me"]
[]
```

The last two lines were the only ones which would consistently work, the first input would ignore the last pair of First and Score, the second input would delete the wrong word if the string was a tie, and third would give an ArrayOutofBounds Exception.

What makes this frustrating is that I thought I made safeguards for each of these errors. I made it so that it would take away one from the size of the array in case it was an odd number of arrays, while the code would make sure not to do an extra i-1 in case it was at 0 to prevent an OutOfBoundsException.

I would greatly appreciate the help, as I understand that there's plenty that I may be doing wrong but I won't get much of a chance to ask my classmates or teacher for a few days.
  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following logic is rather strange:

```
i = i-1;
if((Shorty.get(i)).length()<= (Shorty.get(i-1)).length()){
    Shorty.remove(i);

       if(i != 0){
            i = i-1;
        } 
}
```

Please simplify your code so you'd understand where you're making the mistake. For example you don't need the `else if{...}` clause. Just write `else`. I can spot a few other things you could simplify.

---

```
public static void removeShorterStrings(ArrayList<String> shorty) {

    List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();

    if (shorty.size() < 0 || shorty.size() == 1)
        return;

    if (shorty.size() % 2 == 0)
        for (int i = 0; i < shorty.size(); i += 2) {
            if (shorty.get(i).length() < shorty.get(i + 1).length())
                tmp.add(shorty.get(i + 1));
            else
                tmp.add(shorty.get(i));

        }

    else {
        int i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < shorty.size() - 1; i += 2) {
            if (shorty.get(i).length() < shorty.get(i + 1).length())
                tmp.add(shorty.get(i + 1));
            else
                tmp.add(shorty.get(i));

        }
        tmp.add(shorty.get(shorty.size() - 1));
    }

    shorty.clear();
    for (String s : tmp)
        shorty.add(s);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void removeShorterStrings (ArrayList<String> list){

        for(int i=0;i<list.size()-1;i+=2){
          if(list.get(i).length()<list.get(i+1).length())
                list.set(i,"o345ty34fty");
            else if(list.get(i).length()>list.get(i+1).length())
                list.set(i+1,"o345ty34fty");
                else if(list.get(i).length()==list.get(i+1).length())
                      list.set(i,"o345ty34fty");
        }

        int index=list.indexOf("o345ty34fty");
                  while(index>=0){
                      list.remove(index);
                      index=list.indexOf("o345ty34fty");
                  }

    }
```

I was going through same question I came up with the above logic of setting the shorter string to some random string and then removing it. I know its not the perfect answer but hope it helps.